# Micrometer with Prometheus Pushgateway - Add Basic Auth credentials

Tags: spring-boot, prometheus, micrometer, spring-micrometer, prometheus-pushgateway

I have a Spring boot application with Prometheus Pushgateway using Micrometer, mainly based on this tutorial: https://luramarchanjo.tech/2020/01/05/spring-boot-2.2-and-prometheus-pushgateway-with-micrometer.html

`pom.xml` has following related dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
    <artifactId>micrometer-core</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
    <artifactId>micrometer-registry-prometheus</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.prometheus</groupId>
    <artifactId>simpleclient_pushgateway</artifactId>
    <version>0.16.0</version>
</dependency>
```

And `application.properties` file has:

```
management.metrics.export.prometheus.pushgateway.enabled=false
management.metrics.export.prometheus.pushgateway.shutdown-operation=PUSH
management.metrics.export.prometheus.pushgateway.baseUrl=localhost:9091
```

It is working fine locally in Dev environment while connecting to Pushgateway without any authentication. In our CI environment, Prometheus Pushgateway has basic auth enabled. How do I configure Basic auth credentials in this Spring boot application?

Answer (score 0):

It seems neither [Spring Boot's auto-configuration](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/ed42823bd2e7a526572374a0d25ba4e455ce4aeb/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/metrics/export/prometheus/PrometheusMetricsExportAutoConfiguration.java#L134-L148) not Prometheus' [PushGateway](https://github.com/prometheus/client_java/blob/master/simpleclient_pushgateway/src/main/java/io/prometheus/client/exporter/PushGateway.java#L81) supports providing credentials directly.

I think you can do two things:

1. I'm not sure if it is supported in the HTTP client but some does/did support passing credentials in the url that will be translated to headers: https://serverfault.com/a/371918
2. You can also create your own `PrometheusPushGatewayManager` bean and call `setConnectionFactory` on the `PushGateway` instance with a factory that has the creds before you pass the `PushGateway` to the ctor of `PrometheusPushGatewayManager`.

Comment: Thanks for the response @Jonatan.
I have already tried 1. and still gets 401.
Regarding No 2., once I create my custom`PrometheusPushGatewayManager`, how can I set that bean so that Spring AOP can use it?

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to do with Spring AOP. Read the Spring Boot docs and see how to create a @Bean, once you have one, Spring will use yours.

Comment: I meant actuator. Getting the bean is easy, the trouble is bean for `PrometheusPushGatewayManager` is created under static class `PrometheusPushGatewayConfiguration` under `PrometheusMetricsExportAutoConfiguration`.